# How do I return a value within a loop within a function?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return

I have this almost figured it out but there is one thing.  Basically I want to return a string `without a vowel` (a common challenge I guess).  This is similar to other challenges on CodeWars I have done, still uncompleted due to this.  I have a for loop within a function.  I call the function to return value.

For some reason, I'm returning empty or rather "None", yet I get the result I wanted by printing.  On the same line and indenting.

This is for a Codewar challenge, so I need to return values instead of , printing, logging (I know).  I asked for a friend, hours of researching but nothing could help me.

```py
def disemvowel(string):
    #aeiou
    vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
    aList = list(string) #'' to [...]

    for x in aList:
      for y in vowel:
        if x == y: 
          #print(x)
          aList.remove(x)
    print(''.join(aList)) # "Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!"
    return(''.join(aList)) # Nothing shows up here...
```

I expect the output of `"Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!"` by returning but I get `None`.

https://www.codewars.com/kata/52fba66badcd10859f00097e/train/python
Source ^

Comment: Welcome to SO (and CW)! Just a general message: removing stuff from a list while iterating over it is almost always asking for trouble. Think about maybe creating a new list rather than modifying the original list.

Comment: Oh, I have heard about this.  What should I do instead?  Is this because I'm returning empty?

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the last part.  I will try that and see what I come up with.

Comment: It works fine for me in terms of the return and passes some tests, but there's a bug in the logic related to what I said above so it fails on other tests.

Answer (score 0):

To remove vowels from strings, the quickest way would be to use `str.replace`.

```py
def remove_vowels(msg):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
    for vowel in vowels:
        msg = msg.replace(vowel, '')
    return msg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```py
def remove_vowels(msg):
    return ''.join(c for c in msg if c.lower() not in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'})
```

**Examples:**

```py
>>> remove_vowels("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.")
'Lrm psm dlr st mt.'
>> remove_vowels("This is it")
'Ths s t'
>>> remove_vowels("This website is for losers LOL!")
'Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!'
```

Comment: Would be faster if you made `vowels` a `set` because membership testing would happen more quickly.